# Why do I get the wrong expression for velocity of an electron in Bohr's $n$th orbit?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, electrons, atomic-physics, orbitals

Why do I get the wrong expression for velocity of an electron in bohrs nth orbit?

> Putting $r = \frac{nh}{mv\cdot2\pi}$, we get
>
> \begin{align}
> \require{cancel}
> \require{siunitx}
> mv^2 &= \frac{Ze^2}{\frac{nh}{mv\cdot2\pi}} \\
> \cancel{m}v^{\cancel2} &= \frac{Ze^2}{nh} \cdot \cancel{mv} \cdot 2\pi \\
> v &= \frac{2Ze^2\pi}{nh} \\
> v &= \frac Zn\cdot \frac{2e^2\pi}{h} \\
> v &= \frac Zn \cdot \left(\frac{2\times(1.6022\times10^{-19}\operatorname C)^2}{6.636\times10^{-34}\operatorname J\operatorname s}\times\frac{22}7\right) \\
> v &= \frac Zn \cdot \left(\frac{2\times(1.6022)^2}{6.636\operatorname J\operatorname s}\times10^{-38}\mathrm C^2\times10^{34}\times\frac{22}7\right) \\
> v &= \frac Zn \cdot \left(\frac{2\times(1.6022)^2}{6.636\operatorname J\operatorname s}\times10^{-4}\mathrm C^2\times\frac{22}7\right) \\
> v &= \frac Zn \cdot \left( 2.431 \times 10^{-4} \frac{\mathrm C^2}{\operatorname J\operatorname s} \right)
> \end{align}

[original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0anJ.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using Coulomb's law in the wrong units, in SI units there's the additional factor of $(4\pi\varepsilon_0)^{-1}$ you need to take into account.

This means in your case you have to divide your result by $4\pi\varepsilon_0$ to a) get the correct SI units and b) get the correct numerical value of
$$
v=\frac{Z}{n}\cdot 2.2\cdot10^6\frac{\text{m}}{\text{s}}
$$